# Trying to communicate with an ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, servo

G'day guys, I'm trying to get an ESP8266 to work with an Arduino Uno.
Here is the wiring.
[image: wiringPicture]

When I go to the serial monitor (115200 baud) and type: AT, there is not response from the ESP8266.
Is there something that I am missing?
I also have a servo motor connected, it works fine.

```cpp
include "Arduino.h"
include "ESP8266.h"
include "dweet.h"
include "Servo.h"

define ESP8266_PIN_RX 10
define ESP8266_PIN_TX 11
define SERVO9G_PIN_SIG 2

const int servo9gRestPosition   = 20;
const int servo9gTargetPosition = 150;
const char *SSID     = "Wireless Network";
const char *PASSWORD = "wireless_password";

ESP8266 wifi(ESP8266_PIN_RX,ESP8266_PIN_TX);
Servo servo9g;

const int timeout = 10000;
char menuOption = 0;
long time0;

void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial); //await connection.
   Serial.println("start");

   wifi.init(SSID, PASSWORD);
   servo9g.attach(SERVO9G_PIN_SIG);
   servo9g.write(servo9gRestPosition);
   delay(100);
   servo9g.detach();

}

void loop() 
{ 
   servo9g.attach(SERVO9G_PIN_SIG);       
   servo9g.write(servo9gTargetPosition);  
   delay(500);                            
   servo9g.write(servo9gRestPosition);    
   delay(500);                              
   servo9g.detach(); 
}
```

I'm using the ESP8266 Library.
When trying to connect it just says `Initializing device...`

Comment: Arduino Uno is 5V; ESP8266 is 3.3V. I have tried that combination without level shifters and it doesn't seems to work. Currently I'm using nodeMCU with a Pro Mini, both 3.3V, communicating over I2C. You have two problems here: 1) Communication between Arduino and ESP8266; 2) Communication between ESP8266 and WiFi. Now, nodeMCU is a much capable board than Arduino if you don't need so many I/O pins. Better you discard the Arduino and keep the ESP8266.

Comment: "*115200baud*" and `Serial.begin(9600);`. Something doesn't match. Also powering a motor from an Arduino is never a good idea.

Comment: G'day mate, I have managed to flash the firmware with what I hope is the latest, I did the AT command and it said Ok, however when I did the command that allows you to see wireless networks, it says error. Also how do you reckon I hook the motor up? I read that the motor is 5v so i would have thought that it would be ok?

Comment: @user1234433222 thats another question

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some project constraints which make it mandatory to use naked ESP8266, why not use a NodeMCU to communicate with the Arduino in a master/slave relation over I2C?

[image]

```
#include <Wire.h>  
#define I2CAddressESPWifi 8
```

in `setup()`

```
Wire.begin(D1,D2); // SCL D1 SDA D2
```

then call from anywhere inside your `loop()` call this function

```
char readSlave(int x) { // send current time
  String xY = String(x);
  char c;
  int charArrayLength = xY.length()+1;
  char bufferChar[charArrayLength];
  Wire.beginTransmission(8);
  xY.toCharArray(bufferChar, charArrayLength);
  Wire.write(bufferChar);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(10);
  Serial.print("wire sent: [");
  Serial.print(x);
  delay(50);//Wait for Slave to calculate response.
  int counter = 0;
  char buffMe[32];
  int bytesIn = Wire.requestFrom(8,32);
  while (Wire.available()) {
    delay(2);
    buffMe[counter] = Wire.read();
    /*
    c = Wire.read();
    Serial.print(c);
    */
    counter++;
  }
  delay(10);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("] bytesIn: [");
  Serial.print(bytesIn);
  Serial.print("] buffMe: [");
  Serial.print(buffMe);
  Serial.print("]");
  return buffMe;
}
```

and your arduino will be waiting (`setup`)

```
Serial.begin(9600);
// slave listens for call from master NodeMCU
Wire.begin(I2CAddressESPWifi);  // predefined as `8` or whatever address you choose
Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
```

and at the end of your code

```
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  if (howMany) {
    Serial.print("bytes[");
    Serial.print(howMany);
    Serial.print("] Received[");
    char charIn[howMany];
    int counter = 0;
    while (Wire.available()) {
      char c = Wire.read();
      charIn[counter] = c;
      //Serial.print(c);
      counter++;
    }
    delay(10);
    //do something with command from master
  }
}
void requestEvent() {
  char bufferChar[20] = "slave answer string";  // automatically null terminated extra character at end
  Serial.println(bufferChar);
  Wire.write(bufferChar);
}
```

Comment: thank you, I will purchase one and see how I go :)